# Flutter Page keeps refreshing and can't stop

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I made a flutter app to check if the response of my HTTP request is "TRUE" and then Navigate to another screen. The whole point of testing this is to make a login page. So that I can pass the parameters using the getText() then pass it to the URL later.

The applications works fine, but the Welcome Page keeps flickering. It keeps appearing and going off, and then coming back again. it never stops. Could I know why?

This is my code in the main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'Welcome.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var text;
  void getData() async {
    Response response = await get(
    'http://192.168.8.101/DIVSS%20ENGINE/DivssService.asmx/GetCustomerDetailsForMobile?CustEmail=test&CustPassword=123');
    print(response.body);
    if (response.body == '"TRUE"') {
      Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Welcome(),
    ),
      );
   }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text(text),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your `getData()` call to `initstate()`

```
  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    await getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a state variable to determine what page to

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var text;
  bool isLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  void getData() async {
    Response response = await get(
        'http://192.168.8.101/DIVSS%20ENGINE/DivssService.asmx/GetCustomerDetailsForMobile?CustEmail=test&CustPassword=123');
    print(response.body);
    if (response.body == '"TRUE"') {
      setState(() {
        isLoggedIn = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoggedIn ? Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    ) : Welcome();
  }
}
```

The state variable isLoggedIn will help your widget tree builder to know which widget to build.

Hope the above code helps!

Comment: This worked!!! :D Can I use the Navigator.pop() on the Welcome.dart file to go back to the main.dart file still?

Comment: Yes. If you want to avoid that, do Navigator.pop() on Home Page before navigating to Welcome Page